# Адаптивное меню не скрывается после клика по ссылке из списка меню

Tags: javascript

После клика информация загружается из внешнего файла а открытое меню перекрывает её. В меню присутствует javascript. Меню можно посмотреть на сайте http://www.prorab-service.ru/strrem/strrem.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попытка "пальцем в небо" после минуты просмотра исходников.

```
else {  // 121 строка файла http://www.prorab-service.ru/strrem/js/jquery.dlmenu.js
  self.options.onLinkClick( $item, event );
  self._closeMenu();  // ДОБАВИТЬ ВОТ ТАКУЮ СТРОКУ
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Не большая вставка и все работает отлично.

Answer (score 0):

В функцию `showContent` добавьте:

```
var event = new Event("click");
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("dl-trigger");
elem.dispatchEvent(event);
```